# Ubuntu 20.04, 16 GB ram installed, only 8 GB detected

Tags: 20.04, ram

I got 16 GB of RAM installed for Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit, but only 8 GB are usable. I tried to remove 1 slot of RAM and it turned out I got 12 GB available.

Is there any way for me to make the OS support all 16 GB?

Comment: `sudo dmidecode -t memory` can you add this to your question?  Is something in uefi/bios for memory? I mean something to configure.

Comment: Is this a laptop?   You can run `sudo inxi -m` on your system and that will tell you all the slots and what the array capacity is.  Some laptop motherboards will do like 16GB, but they didn't solder on one of the 4GB modules, so the max they can do is 12GB with 1x4GB soldered on with 2x4GB in the slots.